# encrypt column in the table

Tags: sql-server

I am just wondering if there is a MS technology which allow to transparently encrypt the column of table.

There is a symmetric/assymetric encription which allow to encrypt one column of the table. But this technology is not transparent for user applications. The application needs to open keys and use the ENCRYPTBYKEY/DECRYPTBYKEY functions.

There is TDE which allow to transparently encrypt the database, but it works with databases, backups and transaction log - not one column of database.

Is it possible to transparently encrypt one of the column in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, unless you implement it yourself.

In SQL Server 2008 [TDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is implemented at the database level (no column is_encrypted in sys.databases), so it is the [only way of doing it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx).